# SQL- SSRS Report

Tags: sql

I am building a SSRS report and the data looks like as shown in the attached image.

I need to show the card number separately like primary and secondary based on the flag into new columns along with effective dates. If a customer has more than one card, i want to show the latest card information.

How can i modify my sql script to get the desired output.

Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  I think this is the logic you want:

```
select cif_id, staff_id, package, segment,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 and primary_card_flag = 'Y' then card_number end),
       max(case when seqnum = 1  and primary_card_flag = 'N' then card_number end),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 and primary_card_flag = 'Y' then valid_from_date end),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 and primary_card_flag = 'N' then valid_from_date end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cif_id, staff_id, package, segment, primary_card_flag
                                order by valid_from_date desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by cif_id, staff_id, package, segment order;
```

Comment: Hi, It is giving me same card number for both primary and secondary card columns and primary card effective date in both the places. Below is the input and expected output.

cif_id card_number Primary_card_flag valid_from_date 
1 1234 Y 11/7/2017 
1 1234 Y 11/7/2017 
1 1234 Y 8/21/2017 
1 1234 Y 8/21/2017 
1 4567 N 4/6/2019 
1 4567 N 4/6/2019 
        
    
cif_id Primary_card_nbr Secondary_card_nbr Primary_card_Date Secondary_card_Date
1 1234 4567 11/7/2017 4/6/2019

Comment: I think we need to partition by primary_card_flag also. I tried to modify it but not getting the expected output.

Comment: @viresh . . . Set up a db<>fiddle.  You should also clarify exactly what logic you want for choosing the two accounts.

Comment: Hi, I didn't get db<>fiddle.

currently i have card number and primary_card_flag column. If primary_card_flag  is 'Y' then it is Primary card number and if primary_card_flag is 'N' then it is secondary card number.I need show both the cards in separate columns along with their effective dates. Am i clear? Please let me know if you need any clarifications. Thanks

Comment: @viresh . . . So, why don't you show both primary cards?  But I think the last edit does what you want.

Comment: At any time, a customer will have only one primary card and one secondary card. If more than one line items are there, we need to get the latest records. Some customers will have only primary card and some will have both the cards.